# RGFormsModel Questions Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, forms

What does `RGFormsModel::` mean in Gravity forms? it notice that it's seems to always be calling function, but I'm just looking for a litte more clarification as a lot of documentation on GForms is very basic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the RGFormsModel class (deprecated in favor of GFFormsModel) is a simple class wrapper that contains a variety of functions used to interact with the forms. This class is in the process of being mostly gutted in favor of the GFAPI class which has a host of helpful functions when working with Gravity Forms.

Here is an example where I'm getting the form data where all the form and field settings are stored.

```
// old version
$form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta( $form_id );

// new version
$form = GFAPI::get_form( $form_id );
```

Another useful function I use from the GFFormsModel class (same as RGFormsModel), is:

```
$input_type = GFFormsModel::get_input_type( $field );
```

Comment: This is really great, thanks David. Do you by chance know where they document this change from GFFormsModel to GFAPI?

Comment: Nevermind, documented here: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/api-functions/

Comment: Here are the docs for the GFAPI: https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/