# Gravity Form is not deactivating as expected

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I want to disable the form with the given ID, but it is throwing an error.

```
  RGFormsModel::update_form_meta($form_id, 'is_active', true);
```

> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '1='"is_active"' WHERE form_id=5' at line 1]

Comment: It appears that `RGFormsModel` has been deprecated for almost 10 years. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942558/rgformsmodel-questions-gravity-forms